# simple vector identity

Tags: vectors, absolute-value

i came up with the following:
$$
|\vec{r}+\vec{s}|\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|=|\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2|
$$
here is my calulation:
$$
|\vec{r}+\vec{s}|\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|=\sqrt{(r_x+s_y)^2+(r_y+s_y)^2+(r_z+s_z)^2}\cdot\sqrt{(r_x-s_x)^2+(r_y-s_y)^2+(r_z-s_z)^2}=\sqrt{[(r_x+s_y)^2+(r_y+s_y)^2+(r_z+s_z)^2]\cdot[(r_x-s_x)^2+(r_y-s_y)^2+(r_z-s_z)^2]}=\sqrt{(\vec{r}+\vec{s})\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{s})}=\sqrt{\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2}
$$
but this cant be quite right as $|\vec{r}+\vec{s}|\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|$ cant be complex but $\sqrt{\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2}$ can be complex
I dont know where the mistake is an i hope someone sees it

PS: in the last step I used $(\vec{r}+\vec{s})(\vec{r}-\vec{s})=\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2$

Comment: How did you go from$\sqrt{[(r_x+s_y)^2+(r_y+s_y)^2+(r_z+s_z)^2]*[(r_x-s_x)^2+(r_y-s_y)^2+(r_z-s_z)^2]}$ to $\sqrt{(\vec{r}+\vec{s})*(\vec{r}-\vec{s})}$?  (And what do you mean by $*$ in the latter expression?  The dot product?)

Comment: Can you explain the previous to last step?

Comment: $(\vec{r}+\vec{s})(\vec{r}-\vec{s})=\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2$ makes little sense with vectors - their multiplication does not share the multiplication properties of scalars

Comment: $|\vec{r}+\vec{s}| \cdot |\vec{r}-\vec{s}|=|\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2|$ is not correct.

Comment: At Thomas, Idiotic Shrike.
So in the previous to the last Step I used as I said 
$$
(\vec{r}+\vec{s})(\vec{r}-\vec{s})=\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2
$$
and i came up with this because:
$$
(\vec{r}+\vec{s})(\vec{r}-\vec{s})=(\vec{r}+\vec{s})\cdot\vec{r}-(\vec{r}+\vec{s})\cdot\vec{s}=\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}+\vec{s}\cdot\vec{r}-\vec{r}\cdot\vec{s}-\vec{s}\cdot\vec{s}=\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}-\vec{s}\cdot\vec{s}=\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2
$$

Comment: At Eric Wofsey. With $*$ i mean $\cdot$. So in the first case its the normal multiplication and in the second case its the vector multiplication

Comment: At Math Lover. And why is it not correct ?

Comment: $\vec a \cdot \vec b = |a| \ |b| \cos\theta$ so $|\vec r|^2 - |\vec s|^2 = (\vec r - \vec s) \cdot (\vec r + \vec s) = |\vec r + \vec s| \ |\vec r - \vec s| \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is angle between vectors $(\vec r + \vec s)$ and $(\vec r - \vec s)$

Comment: Ath Math Lover. But how did you show now that $|\vec{r}+\vec{s}|\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|=|\vec{r}^2-\vec{s}^2|$ is not correct?

Comment: *puuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuush. help plssss

Comment: Sorry actually I was meaning to explain the passage that Eric Wofsey pointed out :D that step sounds wrong